# How to download an excel Sheet With a Dialog Box?

Tags: asp.net, excel

I wanted to show a dialog box to the user to save a file where he prefers to. And had written this code to achieve this.

```
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(excelPath);
System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
context.Response.ContentType = "aapplication/xml";
context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + excelPath);
context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
```

This is downloading directly the excel sheet directly without any dialog box, I'm having no clue why it is not showing me dialog box.
My excel sheet is of **.xlsx format**

Comment: What is shown? Which browser? What does the browser's dev tools show in its network tab for this response?

Comment: It may not be making any difference, but the filename in the content-disposition header should be just the file name, and not the entire path

Comment: I'm using **google chrome **, Nothing is being shown @Richard

Comment: .. and you have a typo in ContentType - should be "application/xml" and not "aapplication/xml", and why are you specifying a content type of XML anyway?

Comment: I have given "application/xml" here it was a spelling mistake and I'm writing xml into excel @stuartd

Comment: I have tried just specifying " file name", yet the same result

Comment: ContentType should be application/octet-stream or perhaps application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet but definitely not XML

Comment: Even this seems of no help @stuartd